# My enum is not a class or namespace

Tags: c++, enums, g++, c++11

Hi I have files called MyCode.h and MyCode.cpp

In MyCode.h I have declared

```
enum MyEnum {Something = 0, SomethingElse = 1};

class MyClass {

MyEnum enumInstance;
void Foo();

};
```

Then in MyCode.cpp:

```
#include "MyCode.h"

void MyClass::Foo() {
    enumInstance = MyEnum::SomethingElse;
}
```

but when compiling with g++ I get the error 'MyEnum' is not a class or namespace...

(works fine in MS VS2010 but not linux g++)

Any ideas?
Thanks
Thomas

Comment: Note: in your `.cpp` file, if you wanted to provide an implementation for `MyClass::foo`, the signature would be `void MyClass::Foo() { ... }`. You are missing the `MyClass::` bit.

Comment: MyCode.h != MyClass.h ... Doubt that helps though :P

Answer (score 67, accepted):

The syntax `MyEnum::SomethingElse` is a Microsoft extension.  It happens to be one I like, but it's not Standard C++.  `enum` values are added to the surrounding namespace:

```
 // header
 enum MyEnum {Something = 0, SomethingElse = 1};

 class MyClass {

 MyEnum enumInstance;
 void Foo();

 }

 // implementation
 #include "MyClass.h"

 void Foo() {
     enumInstance = SomethingElse;
 }
```

Comment: Luckily, C++0x will add that capacity, one I think was lacking for quite some time and sorely needed.

Comment: Thanks. It drove me crazy. I couldn't figure out why my enums would resolve in one XCode project and not in the other. O.o
Though I still don't have an answer as to why this happened, I know the fix. If someone ventures a guess, I'd be more than happy to know..

Answer (score 51):

Scoped enums will not exist until C++0x. For the time being, your code should be

```
enumInstance = SomethingElse;
```

You can create an artificial scoped enum by putting the enum's definition inside its own namespace or struct.

Answer (score 31):

Indeed, C++0x allows that feature. I could enable it successfully in gcc using this command line flag: **-std=c++0x**

*This was with gcc version 4.4.5*

Comment: Thanks, helped me to save the time

Answer (score 2):

As explain in other answers: syntax `MyEnum::SomethingElse` is not valid on regular C++98 enums unless your compiler supports them through non-standard extensions.

I personally don't like the declaration `enum MyEnum {A, B};` because Type name is not present while using enum values. This can leads to conflict of names in the current name space.

So user should refer to the type name at each enum values. Example to avoid declaring A twice:

```
enum MyEnum {MyEnum_A, MyEnum_B};
void A(void) {
    MyEnum enumInstance = MyEnum_A;
}
```

I prefer to use a specific name space or structure.
This allow to reference enum values with latest C++ style:

```
namespace MyEnum {
    enum Value {A,B};
}
void A(void) {
    MyEnum::Value enumInstance = MyEnum::A
}
```