# accessing an enum declared in a C++ class

Tags: c++, g++

I declare an enum inside a class and then try to access it a different class. This works perfectly fine with vs2010, but it fails with g++ with the error "not a class or namespace name"

```
//Manager.h
class TestMgr
{
public:
        typedef enum
       {
                kError,
                kRun,
                kFly,
                kDefault = kRun
        }Mode;

};
```

The main function

```
//main.cpp
#include"Manager.h"    
int main()
{

   TestMgr::Mode _mode = TestMgr::Mode::kDefault;

}
```

This gives me a compilation error: ‘TestMgr::Mode’ is not a class or namespace

Please guide.

Edit: I see that there is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5188554/my-enum-is-not-a-class-or-namespace), but that talks about an enum declared globally, not within a class.

Comment: Why exactly are you using `typedef` here? Also you have a typo: `kGDefault `!=`kDefault`.

Comment: you dont show any includes here, did you forget it or arent there any?

Comment: Was keeping the code minimalistic here. I had added the headers while I tried to compile.

Comment: Ok, so figured out that the syntax  TestMgr::Mode::kDefault; doesnt work for GCC. You should use it as TestMgr::kDefault; instead

Answer (score 0):

That compiles to me:

```
class TestMgr
{
public:
        typedef enum Mode
       {
                kError,
                kRun,
                kFly,
                kGDefault = kRun
        }Mode;
};

int main()
{
   TestMgr::Mode _mode = TestMgr::Mode::kGDefault;
}
```